# retention policy and storage in SharePoint Online

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

Not sure where the right place to ask this question is.
Our production tenant has a retention policy to keep all files for 10 years. It adds a lot to our storage requirements.
We need to have an application to periodically move files from one library to another in the same site collection (team site)
this will happen on many sites.

So the question is: will the storage have the moved files twice?
does it work like a file system or a copy then delete?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no files that moved twice in Preservation Hold Library.

**Once the retention policy is applied to your SharePoint Online site(s), You’ll see the below changes:**

[image]

- You’ll see a new library, "**Preservation Hold Library**" on the site
  contents page as soon as you delete any item or edit an existing item
  for the first time. (**This library is visible only to Site collection
  administrators**). You can recover deleted items from it.
- If you try to delete a list or library that has content, you’ll see
  an error message, "List cannot be deleted while on hold or retention
  policy".
- You can't delete a folder with its contents. If you try, you'll face
  the "You have to delete all the items in this folder before you can
  delete the folder" error! You can either use Explorer view or
  PowerShell to delete all files in a folder recursively.

[image]

- You can't delete a site collection from the Admin center (or even
  with PowerShell). You must exclude the site from the retention policy
  to delete the site.
- When a list item or a document is deleted in SharePoint, it goes to
  the recycle bin, and a copy of the item is sent to the Preservation
  Hold library. Also, a copy of the original content is retained in the
  Preservation Hold library when users edit existing documents (that
  are created prior to applying the policy!).

[image]

Comment: I guess I will have to test myself if, when I move a file from one library to another, it will have a copy in "Preservation Hold library". if there is, then it cost twice the storage. Thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: Hi Ofer Gal. When I move a existing file from one library to another in a same site, it will not have a copy in "Preservation Hold library". Have a nice day!